# Emit Events and On Vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, components

Hi this is my parent custom events

```
bus.$emit('updated-users', 'Sample Data')
```

My component

```
bus.$on('updated-users', data => this.lastname = data)
```

This one works.

Using Callback doesn't work.

```
bus.$on('updated-users', function(data){
        //data is displayed in the console log.
        console.log(data)
        //This doesn't work. 
        this.fetchedUsersData()
    })
```

I need to trigger a method but it doesn't work. I can't find any example that trigger a method. Please help.

Comment: Unbound `this` used in your function.

Comment: Hi what do you mean unbound `this`. Is it `fetchedUsersData()` only?

Comment: @kirqe The example is from child to parent. Mine is from parent to child. Is it still the same concept? TY

Comment: @kirqe the one you've posted needs a data not to trigger a function. I think it's not duplicate. TY

Comment: In both cases you are using a callback function, you are just defining the function in different ways,  The specific issue is the difference in how `this` is bound between arrow functions and regular functions. Arrow functions are bound lexically, meaning `this` will point to the Vue. In the second example, `this` will probably point to the `bus`, which doesn't have a `fetchedUsersData` method.

Comment: @BertEvans Thanks I have solved it with your explanation. Here is my code `bus.$on('updated-users', data => {this.fetchUserData()})`. Hard to understand but I did it. You are a rockstar in many times!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
created () {
 bus.$on('updated-users', fetchedUsersData)
},
methods: {
 fetchedUsersData(){
  //the fetched user data
  console.log('the fetched user data')
 }
}
```